# Как правильно организовать динамическую пагинацию?

Tags: java, jquery, jsp, pagination, datatable

Использую jQuery c DataTables. 
На сайте [DataTables](https://datatables.net/development/server-side/jsp) нашел реализацию пагинации, в которой непосредственно `JSP` лезет в базу, что, как мне кажется, очень и очень плохая практика. Так вот может есть какие то варианты сделать пагинацию соблюдая MVC? Или же только пилить свою `DataTable` с пагинацией и кнопочками? Вариант перехода на какой то фреймворк (Angular, React) Пока не рассматривается, целью является поверхностное знакомство с `JS`

Посмотрев внимательнее, спасибо комментариям, вопрос о том что `view` лезет в базу отпал, так как `JSP` в данном случае выступает контроллером. Но назрел следующий вопрос. Зачем реализовывать контроллер в виде `JSP`? Какие преймущества/недостатки?

Comment: Два вопроса: 1) почему считаете, что такая практика плоха; 2) в чем вы видите несоблюдение MVC в данном случае?

Comment: @Станислав, mvc подразумевает разграничение приложения на три основных части, где каждая отвечает сугубо за свой участок. И как мне кажется View(JSP) не должна лезть в базу минуя модель и контроллер

Comment: Прошу прощения, а где вы там увидели, что JS-скрипт полезет сам в базу? Он обратится к некоему скрипту (php, etc), который и будет являться частью MVC, а именно `Controller`, который будет отдавать тот или иной ответ в зависимости от параметров запроса. Именно в нем будет реализован через тот или иной механизм работы с базой данных, получение очередной страницы и ее отдача во `View`, а не сам `View` будет создавать подключение к базе, делать SELECT и прочее.

Comment: @Станислав Нет, это я прошу прощения) я даже не просмотрев полностью пример закрыл его, увидев что из JSP лезут в базу, не обратив внимания что происходит дальше. Да действительно данная JSP выступает контроллером, хотя её можно полностью перетащить в "нормальный" контроллер.

Comment: Не вопрос :) Я тогда оформлю этот комментарий как ответ, можете его потом принять как верный.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> очень и очень плохая практика

Это вполне себе стандартная практика.

> Так вот может есть какие то варианты сделать пагинацию соблюдая MVC

На самом деле, все соблюдается. Выбранный вами плагин для `JQuery` обратится к некоему скрипту (`php`, etc), который и будет являться частью `MVC`, а именно `Controller`, который будет отдавать тот или иной ответ в зависимости от параметров запроса. Именно в нем будет реализован через тот или иной механизм работы с базой данных, получение очередной страницы и ее отдача во `View`, а не сам `View` (то есть тот самый JS-код выбранного вами плагина) будет создавать подключение к базе, делать `SELECT` и прочее.